# TeXstudio compatibility with Windows 11

Tags: texstudio, windows, texlive-2021

I am configuring a new Windows 11 machine.  I've installed TeX Live 2021, and TeXstudio 4.2.2, both apparently without incident.

When I try to run TeXstudio, I am told: "application was unable to start correctly" and given error code 0xc000007b.

I have uninstalled TeXstudio and reinstalled it.  I have restarted the computer.  I have run TeXstudio in 'compatibility' mode (which reinstalls it with Windows 8 compatibility - the most recent version of Windows offered).  In all cases, TeXstudio just crashes again.

Comment: The right place to search for and report such crashes is the texstudio bug tracker.  https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues

Comment: If I may add to the issue. There are already a few 'reports' in texstudio github (the issue seems related to qt6). unfortunately, the moderators over there seem too eager to close any such report right away, 'oh, it relates to YOUR install only', or 'no one else have reported such a problem' or 'it is not a bug, but a feature' kind of reply... :/
I have, since my last 'interaction' with them, just switched over to use Microsoft Visual Studio Code (it has it quirks as well, but an overall better solution) and emacs (still the best solution for plain coding).

Comment: for instance: 
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1807
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/2697
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/2664